# Selenium - Identifying an HTML element without an ID or CSS class name

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium WebDriver in Python 3 to scrape [this webpage](https://www.southwest.com/air/booking/select.html?originationAirportCode=HOU&destinationAirportCode=MDW&returnAirportCode=&departureDate=2018-05-12&departureTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&returnDate=2018-05-14&returnTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&adultPassengersCount=2&seniorPassengersCount=0&fareType=USD&passengerType=ADULT&tripType=roundtrip&promoCode=&reset=true&redirectToVision=true&leapfrogRequest=true)/[relevant HTML (Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/Bj8w4J4v) and am trying to get a list of prices in the "Departing flights" div. This div does not have an ID nor does it have a CSS class name, so I tried identifying it via XPath. On the Pastebin, to find the div that I'm talking about, Ctrl + F `<div class="">`.

Here is my code:

```
outbound_fares = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='air-booking-product-0']/div[4]")
outbound_prices = outbound_fares.find_elements_by_class_name("currency_dollars")
```

The first line should identify the div and the second line should get a list of all the prices within that div. However, I find that `outbound_prices` is empty. My guess is that the first line is wrong, but I'm not sure how to properly identify the div. Thanks.

Comment: I see "Access denied" message on the link that you have provided. Could you include the relevant part of HTML in your question?

Comment: @K.B. Sure. I have edited the OP with a Pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/Bj8w4J4v

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cssSelector and get the all prices from Depart flights :

**cssSelector :**

```
div[class='fare-button--hybrid'] span>span[class*='screen-reader']
```

try out this cssSelector and let me know the status.
Please let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not Python code and will not work in Selenium.

Comment: It's just a locator, it is independent of language.

Comment: Use this code in python : 
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='fare-button--hybrid'] span>span[class*='screen-reader'] ")

Answer (score 0):

The element you want doesn't have an ID but I don't know what you mean by "does not have a CSS selector." Another locator may be more efficient at finding it, etc. but every element on the page can be found by a CSS selector.

You can use this CSS selector to return all the prices on the page.

```
span.fare-button--value-total
```

Here are some references to read to learn more about CSS selectors and how to use them.

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview

https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies -- I confused CSS selector with CSS class name. It doesn't have a class name.